# struts2 conventions plugin not working properly

Tags: java, struts2, struts-validation, action-mapping, struts2-convention-plugin

I was trying to run the application with convention plugin Struts2. The application was fine with `struts.xml` configured like this:

```
<struts>

    <package name="struts2demo" extends="struts-default">
    <action name="hey" class="action.CountryAction" method="get">
       <result name="success">/index.jsp</result>
    </action>
    <action name="add" class="action.CountryAction" method="add">
       <result type="redirect" name="success">hey</result>
    </action>
    <!-- Add your actions here -->
    </package>

</struts>
```

now I removed that `struts.xml` and added some annotations like this:

```
@Namespace("/")
@ResultPath(value="/")
public class CountryAction extends ActionSupport implements ModelDriven<Country>{
    private List<Country> worldCountry;
    private Country country = new Country();



    public Country getCountry() {
            return country;
        }

    public void setCountry(Country country) {
            this.country = country;
        }

 //   HttpServletRequest request;
@Action(value="/hey",results={@Result(name="success",location="/index.jsp")})
    public String get() throws SQLException
    {
        CountryService cs = new CountryService();
        setWorldCountry(cs.getCountry());
      //  System.out.println(getWorldCountry());
        return SUCCESS;
    }

     public List<Country> getWorldCountry() {
        return worldCountry;
    }

    public void setWorldCountry(List<Country> worldCountry) {
        this.worldCountry = worldCountry;
    }

    @Override
    public Country getModel() {
        return country;
    }
}
```

but when I am trying to run the application i am getting the following error:

**Messages:**

```
There is no Action mapped for namespace [/] and action name [hey] associated with context path [/JustStruts2].
```

**My `web.xml` is this:**

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
         <param-name>struts.devMode</param-name>
         <param-value>true</param-value>
      </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

Where I am doing wrong, any help will be appreciated.
 
Regards.

Comment: asm-commons.jar to solve this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the message the Struts inform you `[hey]` not found in your action configuration. In the `struts.xml` you defined it without slash. Do the same in the annotation. Don't map `index.jsp` that could be handled by the container itself but not by Struts2. The name "success" is used by default, so it's not necessary.

```
@Action(value="hey", results = { @Result(location="/page.jsp") })
```

Note that `@ResultPath` is not necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I changed it to @Action(value="hey", results = { @Result(location="/success.jsp") }) and removed @ResultPath. Still the same problem. Any other solution please, not able to find on net also. :(

Comment: did you try hey.action? did you rename index.jsp? There's also convention plugin on the classpath.

Comment: hey.action also not working. I did not rename index.jsp. Ya conventionplugin is on class path I am using netbeans so i added it in libraries along with other jars. Is it required that i have to use POM.xml to describe the dependencies? I think netbeans will do this already wright?

Comment: jars should be also in the WEB-INF/lib of deployed app.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is solved, i was missing asm-commons.jar. Thanks