# There is no Action mapped for namespace [/] and action name [actionName] associated with context path [/projectName].

Tags: struts2, action-mapping

I am working on struts 2.0 using annotations and created a web project in which I am just doing a login and redirecting on successful login to another jsp. However, whenever i try to login, it shows me an error message :-
             There is no Action mapped for namespace [/] and action name [welcome] associated with context path [/strutsDemo2].

I have added the following jar files into my project:

asm-3.3.jar
   asm-all-2.2.3.jar
   cglib-nodep-2.2.3.jar
   commons-fileupload-1.3.jar
   commons-io-2.0.1.jar
   commons-lang3-3.1.jar
   freemarker-2.3.19.jar
   javassist-3.11.0.GA.jar
   ognl-3.0.6.jar
   struts2-convention-plugin-2.3.15.1.jar
   struts2-core-2.3.15.1.jar
   xwork-core-2.3.15.1.jar

My jsp is:

```
   <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
  pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
 <%@taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
<s:form action="welcome" validate="true">
    <s:textfield name="userName" label="userName"></s:textfield>

    <s:submit value="submit"></s:submit>
</s:form>
</body>
</html>
```

and my action class is:

```
         import org.apache.struts2.convention.annotation.Action;
         import org.apache.struts2.convention.annotation.Namespace;
    import org.apache.struts2.convention.annotation.Result;
    import org.apache.struts2.convention.annotation.ResultPath;
    import org.apache.struts2.convention.annotation.Results;

    import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
    import com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.annotations.RequiredStringValidator;
    import com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.annotations.ValidatorType;

@Namespace("/")
@ResultPath("/")

@Results({
       @Result(name="success", location="/Welcome.jsp"),
       @Result(name="input", location="/index.jsp")
    })
public class Welcome extends ActionSupport{

    private String userName;
    private String message;

    @RequiredStringValidator(type=ValidatorType.FIELD, message="Name is Required")
    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }
    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }
    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    @Action(value="welcome")
    public String execute()
    {
        return SUCCESS;
    }



}
```

Web.xml:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>strutsDemo2</display-name>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
    </filter-class>
    <init-param>
         <param-name>struts.devMode</param-name>
         <param-value>true</param-value>
      </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Your `@ResultPath` annotation is wrong: http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/convention-plugin.html#ConventionPlugin-ResultPathannotation

Comment: it is still showing me the same error, after I changed the @ResultPath

Comment: So, you're not using Struts 2.0.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15828845/struts2-conventions-plugin-not-working-properly/15830397#15830397

Answer (score 0):

Please change your `<s:form action="welcome" validate="true">` to `<s:form action="Welcome" validate="true">`.

In action attribute of  tag use "Welcome" instead of "welcome". Upper case of "W"

Comment: Hey Jay, it is still not working with it. I have also added my jar files correctly but nothing helped out.

Comment: Please make it as you write it and try to put "/" before your action value.
ex. ` @Action(value="/welcome")
    public String execute()
    {
        return SUCCESS;
    }`

Comment: And if try this with maven project then you don't want to messup with this jar files